# Custom Image iPhone Keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

Before this question is dismissed, let me start by saying I've read the dozens of questions that sound similar. I haven't found anyone that has asked for this specific use case, though, so I'm going to give it a shot.

I would like to create custom images to use (similar to emojis) in a custom keyboard that can be accessed with the globe icon. I understand that I can create a custom keyboard inside my own app, but it will only work within that app. I also understand how the emoji keyboard works.

Is it possible to create a situation where if two people are using the app, though, that the keyboard could be used to input the custom images (emojis) and be viewed only by a receiving user that ALSO has the app - even if the keyboard is being used outside of the custom image keyboard app.

So, basically, there would be a set of images stored within the app and the custom keyboard would reference those images to display whenever the keystroke has been entered and then the receiving phone can locate those images stored within the app to display them (but this could all be done within the native SMS messaging app, not solely in the new custom image keyboard app).

I've researched this a good deal, but can't find a straight answer. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own Keyboard that creates somehow special Strings that imply an image. For example could a smiley be encoded like ".CoolSmiley". When you now want to display that text, you should search for patterns you want to recognise. That's how emoji is working. When you type in (y) it will get replaced by a thumb up image because it's recognising the string as a known pattern for a thumb up. This will of course just work inside your app.

Comment: I understand this is how it would work within the app, but I'm trying to create a keyboard that can be used anywhere on the phone. I realize that the images wouldn't be seen by people that don't have the app if they are receiving the SMS/email on a device that doesn't have the app installed.

Comment: No, you can't make a keyboard that works anywhere on the phone. Only in your own app.